# Strange result when redirecting shell in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Let's assume that I have a small makefile like this:

```
all:
        @echo -n -e \\x64
```

If I run make, I see the character `d` is printed. Now if I write my shell code like this:

```
all:
        @echo -n -e \\x64 >> $@
```

I expected that a file called `all` is created which has a content equal `d`. But to my surprise, the content was `-e \x64`. Any idea why this happens and how to solve it? I should say if I run command directly from shell, it works as expected.

Comment: The default shell that make uses to execute the recipes is `sh`. This could explain why the behaviour is not the same when you execute this directly from shell, which is probably not `sh`. If you launch a `sh` shell and try `echo -n -e \\x64` you'll see `d` but if you try `echo -n -e \\x64 > all; cat all` you'll see `-n -e d`, probably because this `echo` has a different behaviour when the output is the terminal than when it is a file. We would need its manual. Anyway, prefer `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non-standard behavior.  The standard for `echo` defines *no* options and has *no* special treatment of escaped characters.  That means that different implementations of `echo` behave differently in situations where you pass options or use escaped characters.

And, there are many implementations to choose from even on a single system, not to mention if you wanted to use this makefile on other systems.  There's the `echo` built into the `bash` shell or other shells that you might be using, and there's the `/bin/echo` program on your system.

As mentioned in the comment above, when make runs it doesn't use `bash`, and sometimes it doesn't even run a shell at all (if the command line is "simple enough") it just invokes the command directly.

If you want to do fancy things like this you shouldn't be using `echo`; instead you should use the `printf` program which has well-defined and standard behavior for avoiding newlines and printing escaped characters.

Only ever use `echo` to show simple strings with no special behavior or characters.

Comment: I cannot accept this as an answer because before posting question, I tried `printf` rather than `echo` and I had exactly same problem. neither `echo` nor `printf` support `\x` in `sh`. If I add `SHELL=bash`, it solves the problem.

Comment: Since you didn't show us the actual code you tried we can't say for sure, but if the problem was "fixed" by switching shells then it's because you're not letting printf print the character, instead you're relying on the shell to do it and passing it as an argument to printf.  You have to put the special character into the format string in `printf`.  See the man page; it definitely supports printing special chars with backslash values.  Try running `printf '\x64'` and you'll get `d` with no newline.

Comment: Yea, if I run it directly I will get `d`. But if I run it in a make file without `SHELL=bash`, it will output `\x64`. Even in the man if `printf` says that how it works depend on shell.

Comment: The man page doesn't exactly say that.  But I did reread the POSIX spec for `printf` and I realize that `\xHH` is not a format defined by POSIX, so you're right that how it is interpreted depends on which `printf` you're using.  However, `\OOO` where `OOO` is an _octal_ string **IS** defined by POSIX, so if you use that form it will work the same in every `printf` implementation regardless of shell: `printf '\144'` will show `d` in every shell and also in the native `/usr/bin/printf` utility.  So if you want to be portable use octal, not hex, in your escape sequences.